# How do I recover a file deleted from git using filter branch and pushed to remote?

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch, git-reset, git-reflog

I recently cleaned out several files from my repository using git filter branch. These are the instructions I followed : https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/. After that I rebased my development branch so that new commits on that branch would not reintroduce any of the history. But in the process, I forgot that I had made changes to a file on this branch which I deleted on the filtered branch. So when I rebased the dev branch, that file disappeared. Is it possible to recover this file?

So far I have tried doing a git reflog to see which commit I could go back to that would have this file. When I used git reset --hard using an old commit hash, I get this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '07a8efd': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
```

I believe this error could be because I had performed a filter branch and force pushed the filtered history back to remote. The cleanup instructions also had a

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

which also explains why that particular commit cannot be found. 
Is there anything I can do in this situation to recover this file?

EDIT: Since the rebase, I have made several more changes to the dev branch, so it would be very helpful to find an option that doesn't involve letting go of all this work.

Comment: I guess you could always check the original revisions (they should still be on reflog, right?)

Comment: Oh! You cleaned your reflog. That's sad. Do you have a remote where the old branches could be present?

Comment: @eftshift0 : I think the git reflog expire command got rid of the original revisions. if I look in ./git/refs/original/refs/remotes/origin, there is nothing.

Comment: @eftshift0 : I can get a super old version of my file, but that's not helpful for me because I made a bunch of changes to it on my dev branch